# Is there a way to temporarily store information between Application.Restart(...) calls in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a C# application where the user has the option to restart, which is essentially a button tied directly to `Application.Restart(...)`.  This works well.

Unfortunately there is some non-critical data I wish to carry between sessions like window sizes and dropdown selections, and currently I do not have any data store the application is connected to that can be used as scratch.  Is there some .NET (or Windows) provided store for a small amount of non-critical non-security-sensitive data I can use for this purpose?

Comment: The bindable Project.Settings (also accessible through ApplicationSettings in .Net Framework <- for now).

Comment: You can use temporary files, or for very small data also the registry.

Comment: maybe use app.config ?

Comment: Just don't use `Application.Restart()`? Your code has a known entry point. Re-factor your code so it resets everything to the way it should be, keeps the things you want, and then goes back to the "beginning" using some kind of looping structure. `Application.Restart()` is just the lazy way out...

Comment: @Idle_Mind Sometimes the choice is between the quick way or nothing.

Comment: I tend to write XML in _IsolatedStorage_ for data like that - mostly because I wrote some well tested code to do that 10 or 15 years ago

Comment: User settings might work, supported out of the box.

Comment: How about [`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings)?

Answer (score 1):

Well here is a quick and dirty way how I would retain any settings upon application restarts:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace RetainSettings
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        NameValueCollection EnvironmentSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
        private int EnvHeight;
        private int EnvWidth;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadAppConfig("Height");
            LoadAppConfig("Width");
        }

        private void UpdateAppConfig(string key, object value)
        {
            Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            config.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value.ToString();
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
        }

        private void LoadAppConfig(string ConfigKey)
        {
            switch (ConfigKey)
            {
                case "Height":
                    EnvHeight = int.Parse(EnvironmentSettings[ConfigKey]);
                    break;
                case "Width":
                    EnvWidth = int.Parse(EnvironmentSettings[ConfigKey]);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Height = EnvHeight;
            Width = EnvWidth;
        }

        private void RestartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateAppConfig("Height", Height);
            UpdateAppConfig("Width", Width);

            Application.Restart();
        }
    }
}
```

---

### `UpdateAppConfig(string, object)`

Note that this method is opening the executable configuration file that is generated inside the `bin` folder along with the executable. This file will have name as same as the exe file with an extenion **.config** appended in the end.

The flow is pretty much understandable if you read this method once. First the config file is loaded then any modifications are done and finally saving the config file which obviously flushes the changes to disk.

---

### `LoadAppConfig(string)`

In this method you can see I've specified the keys that I might want to load from the configuration file. In this example I have used to Height and Width of the form to be retained upon restart.

---

### Important!

If you open the configuration file of a newly created project you'll see that its an XML document and a section `<appSettings></appSettings>` is missing.

For this project I've added the section and the keys to be retained manually like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" />
    </startup>

<!-- Manually Added -->
<appSettings>
  <add key="Height" value="463" />
  <add key="Width" value="558" />
 </appSettings>
 
</configuration>
```

---

### Finally

The `LoadAppConfig` is added in Application's constructor and `UpdateAppConfig` is called just before the restart to update the configuration.

This isn't a concrete answer and I hope experts here will also shed some light on other methods too.